# Flutter Android Release Build Results in ApiException 10

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've pushed an Alpha version of my app up to the PlayStore, but as soon as I try to authenticate within the app I get the "ApiException 10" which usually means that my signing configuration is incorrect. However, I've triple checked all of those configs and I can't find anything wrong. This is what is in my build.gradle file:

```
    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Those keystoreProperties point to a jks file and I've verified that the alias, password, etc. are all correct. I've also checked in the Firebase console and the SHA1 fingerprint of the key is in there.

It does work fine if I run it locally in debug mode, but as soon as I build a release that I push up to the PlayStore, it fails. I'm not quite sure what else to check, so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are building app bundle and/or you enrolled in Google managed app signing, then, you need to add the SHA1 hash of the key google uses to sign your app

Comment: @dlohani aha, that was it! I did not have the Google signing key in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have update your release sha in firebase as well as fill form of your application on google console mostly  ApiException 10 becuase of wrong sha so please have look, as well as credentials set up in console as well.